# multiframe within multido does not work

Tags: pstricks, animate, multido

I try to have several `\multiframes` using `\multido`. But the following minimal example program (which should result in an animation of a growing rotating wedge) gives the error:
`! Package animate Error: Content of first frame must not have zero width.` The code looks like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-sigsys}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[final]{animate}

\newcommand{\mywedge}[2]{%
    \pspicture*(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \degrees[4]
    \pscircle(0,0){#2}
    \pswedge[linestyle=solid,fillcolor=teal,fillstyle=solid]{#2}{#1}{\inteval{#1+1}}
    \endpspicture
}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls={play,step}]{2}
\multido{\iradius=1+1}{4}{%
    \multiframe{4}{iangle=0+1}{%
        \mywedge{\iangle}{\iradius}
    }
    \newframe
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Omitting the `\multido` and the then useless `\newframe` (and providing a number instead of `\iradius` as the second argument to `\mywedge`) gives the expected result (but then of course the wedge doesn't grow anymore). Why doesn't this work and how do I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\multido` *with embedded* `\newframe` does not work well inside `animateinline`. `\newframe` closes a TeX group and thereby hides `\iradius` which is locally defined by `\multido`.

As a fix I would use one of the LaTeX3 stepping functions, e. g.   `\int_step_inline:nnnn`. (See `texdoc interface3`.) Also, the last loop iteration should not insert a `\newframe`. Otherwise, an empty frame would be inserted at the end of the animation. An integer conditional is used to prevent this.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pst-sigsys} 
\usepackage[final]{animate} 
 
\ExplSyntaxOn 
\let\intStepInlinennnn\int_step_inline:nnnn 
\let\intComparenT\int_compare:nT 
\ExplSyntaxOff 
 
\newcommand{\mywedge}[2]{% 
    \pspicture*(-5,-5)(5,5) 
    \degrees[4] 
    \pscircle(0,0){#2} 
    \pswedge[linestyle=solid,fillcolor=teal,fillstyle=solid]{#2}{#1}{\inteval{#1+1}} 
    \endpspicture 
} 
 
\begin{document} 
\begin{animateinline}[controls={play,step}]{2} 
\intStepInlinennnn{1}{1}{4}{% 
  \multiframe{4}{iangle=0+1}{% 
      \mywedge{\iangle}{#1} 
  } 
  \intComparenT{#1<4}{\newframe} 
} 
\end{animateinline} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, that works exactly like I want it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
\begin{animateinline}[controls={play,step}]{2}
    \psLoop{4}{%
        \multiframe{4}{iangle=0+1}{%
            \mywedge{\iangle}{\psLoopIndex}
        }
        \newframe
    }
\end{animateinline}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion! I bookmarked you answer.

Comment: Also cool, thanks! Had to search for a while to find the documentation of \psLoop